# fixed frame for rviz doesn't change

Tags: ros, rviz, fixed-frame

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder why i can't setup my own frame  which i named my own frame by name "my_frame" in my

> tracker_params2.yaml

```
command_rate: 0.5
tracking_rate: 10
base_controller_rate: 20
joint_controller_rate: 20
default_joint_speed: 2.0
max_drive_speed: 0.5
max_rotation_speed: 0.5
base_control_side: right

use_real_robot: False

# Use these values for a typical non-holonomic robot.
scale_drive_speed: 1.0
scale_rotation_speed: 1.0
reverse_rotation: False
holonomic: False

# Use the following scale factors for the Rovio.
#scale_drive_speed: 4.0
#scale_rotation_speed: 0.4
#reverse_rotation: True
#holonomic: True

#fixed_frame: openni_depth_frame
fixed_frame: my_frame

skel_to_joint_map: {
   head: head_pan_joint,
   neck: head_tilt_joint,
   torso: torso_joint,
   left_shoulder: left_shoulder_lift_joint,
   left_elbow: left_elbow_joint,
   left_hand: left_hand_joint,
   right_shoulder: right_shoulder_joint,
   right_elbow: right_elbow_joint,
   right_hand: right_hand_joint,
   left_hip: hip_left_yaw,
   left_knee: knee_left_pitch,
   left_foot: ankle_left_roll,
   right_hip: hip_right_yaw,
   right_knee: knee_right_pitch,
   right_foot: ankle_right_roll
}
```

the ros itself has recognize "my_frame" such in this image:
[image: parameter]

but when i want to called it in rviz, it won't show anything like this:
[image: rviz]

how to set my fixed frame to "my_frame" then?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220983/fixed-frame-for-rviz-doesn%27t-change/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to use the frame_id field in the ROS message header to add to the fixed frame list. Use TF to create transformations between the frames.

---

Originally posted by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) with karma: 275 on 2015-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2015-11-16**:
Sorry, i don't really get what u mean.. i have message named Skeleton.msg that consist

```
Header header
Blablabla... such in tutorial
```

"Use TF to create transformations between the frames."
What is this mean? Do i hv to add TF in rviz?

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2015-11-18**:
The Header in your message above has a member that is "frame_id". It's a text field. AFAIK, this should be matched to one of the frame ids (i.e.  frame_id or childframe_id) in the tf transformation. Additionally, the frame_id's in the header are the ones that are displayed in rviz.

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2015-11-18**:
You might also try finding (via "rostopic echo /topicname |grep frame") a message with the frame_id completed. You could then go to the wiki or github page for that package and look at the source for that frame name. In that way you'd have a example of how to complete the header and the frame_id.

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2015-11-20**:
When i writedown `rostopic echo /topicname | grep frame` the result is always

```
....
frame_locked:   False
   frame_id:   /my_frame
frame_locked:   False
   frame_id:   /my_frame
....
```

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2015-11-30**:
The frame_id is what should show up in rviz. I don't think you need the "/" because I'm not sure the namespace concept extends to frames.